# Scala "illegal start of simple expression" when defining a function

Tags: scala

I am getting the following error on Scala:

```
scala> :pas
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

// sum takes a function that takes an integer and returns an integer then
// returns a function that takes two integers and returns an integer
def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int =
  def sumf(a: Int, b: Int): Int = f(a) + f(b)
  sumf

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:4: error: illegal start of simple expression
  def sumf(a: Int, b: Int): Int = f(a) + f(b)
  ^
```

I am not understanding why `def` is an `illegal start of simple expression`. I am simply trying to declare a function. Am I violating any syntax requirements in the declaration? Thank you.

UPDATE: This is my version of Scala:

```
sbt:jaime> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.14).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

Comment: I would guess you need braces for declaring a nested method. Although, in this, you don't need to do that, you can just define a function directly: `(a, b) => f(a) + f(b)`

Comment: It works using `def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = (a, b) => f(a) + f(b)` as you said @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. Please write it as an answer to mark this question as solved. Thank you! It also works using curly braces as you said by the way.

Comment: Running on Scala 3.0.0, the nested function is accepted as-is. It's possible you were looking at some example code intended for Scala 3 but are running it in Scala 2, which doesn't do indentation-sensitivity.

Comment: True @SilvioMayolo. I am running Scala 2.12.10 and most likely the example code I was trying to run was intended for Scala 3. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to make it work, as Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez mentioned in the comment to this question.

```
scala> :pas
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {
  def sumf(a: Int, b: Int): Int = f(a) + f(b)
  sumf
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

sum: (f: Int => Int)(Int, Int) => Int

scala> :pas
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = (a, b) => f(a) + f(b)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

sum: (f: Int => Int)(Int, Int) => Int

scala>
```